# Multicasting on Raspberry Pi router

Tags: java, c++, linux, networking, raspberry-pi

I am trying to set up a program that streams my webcam over a local network but I'm running into some problems. I made a program in C++ that uses OpenCV to capture the image from my webcam and then I get the bytes and cast it to an IP using multicast. I then have a program in Java that listens to this IP address.

On my usual network created by my router everything works, I'm able to stream my webcam to multiple computers. The problem is, I've set up a Raspberry Pi as a router (using this [link](https://jacobsalmela.com/2014/05/19/raspberry-pi-and-routing-turning-a-pi-into-a-router/)) and whenever I'm on the network the raspberry Pi is creating I cannot multicast.

In the C++ program, I use "sendto" from sys/socket.h to send the data and it returns -1 with the error `Network is unreachable`. When I try to use the java program to listen to the IP I get the following error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: No such device at
>   java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.join(Native Method) at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.join(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:178)
>   at java.net.MulticastSocket.joinGroup(MulticastSocket.java:323) at
>   MulticastImageReciever.(MulticastImageReciever.java:29) at
>   MulticastImageReciever.main(MulticastImageReciever.java:118)

I can post the program I wrote if needed but since it works on the other network I don't think that's the problem. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

The only help I have been able to find is this [link](http://troglobit.github.io/multicast-howto.html), which says the a common problem when using multicast is TTL is set to 1, but this is set by the sender, correct? if so this shouldn't be the problem because I use the same computer on both networks.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Multicast is limited to a broadcast domain, unless you use multicast routing, which is very different than unicast routing. You need special software to respond to IGMP, and you need to use PIM if you need router-to-router multicast routing.

Comment: I do want to use multicast: need to send to many receivers, don't care if the package is lost (to an extent), and I don't always know what computers will be sending/receiving data (With that being said I am open to other options if they meet that). 
I don't think I need router-to-router communication. I just need to be able to multicast to other computers on the same network. The problem is when I use a router (i.e. arris router) multicasting works with my program. When I use a Linux computer as a router (link above) it does not work. If its on the same network will i need other software?

Comment: You need your router to use IGMP. Modern switches do not flood multicast to every interface, they listen to the IGMP conversations between a host and a multicast router to determine which interfaces should receive the multicast. A receiver on the other side of a router that doesn't use IGMP will never be able to let the switch on the source side of the router to send the multicast to the router.

Comment: Multicast routing is very different than unicast routing, and it requires special software.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across a similar problem with the help of the commits I found a solution.

First, since I was using my Raspberry Pi as a router I had to route the multicast packets from [any interface to my wireless interface](https://sites.google.com/site/miclinuxcorner/technology/multicast-routing). In my case on my pi I ran `route add –net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 gw wlan0`. This allowed the router to use IGMP.

Second, Linux kernels after 2.6 [replying to broadcast/multicast is disabled by default](https://0x657573.wordpress.com/2010/11/22/localhost-does-not-response-to-ping-to-multicast-address-224-0-0-1/). To change this `echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts`